# I have a 2 concurrent data structures and I want to update them atomically

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentmodification, atomic

How to make sure that these two concurrent data structure statements get executed as an atomic block without using `synchronized` statement
so that the sum is consistent at any given point in time?

**Note** : *I am new to multi-threading in java.*

```
AtomicLong sumOfAllItems=new AtomicLong();
AtomicLong itemSpecificSum=new AtomicLong();

public void addPrice(long price){
    // how to make sure that these two statements get executed 
    // with synchronised() block

    sumOfAllItems.addAndGet(price);
    itemSpecificSum.addAndGet(price);
}
```

Comment: Why avoid `synchronized`?

Comment: I would go with `synchronized` as well. You can get it to work with`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`

Comment: Why do you need synchronization? `sumOfAllItems` and `itemSpecificSum` are safe because they are atomic classes. It's good as it is.

Comment: Each of the sums are atomic, but he wants the combined statements to be atomic. I'd go with synchronized also.

Comment: The comment in the code suggests to use `synchronized` as well

Comment: @NomadMaker What's the point of make them atomic?

Comment: You can imagine a method in a different thread that gets both values and performs some computation on them, and expects them to be updated at the same time. IMO very reasonable to want this block to be `symchronized`. I am however confused by wanting to avoid using `synchronized`...

Comment: The reason for making it atomic is that there are two background services that return both the results and I want the ```sumOfAllItems``` to be equal to aggregated sum of all ```itemSpecificSum``` at any given point in time.

Comment: Your question says *without* but in your code you say *with* `synchronized`. One is a typo, please check and correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method from this:

```
public void addPrice(long price) {
    // ...    
}
```

to this:

```
public synchronized void addPrice(long price) {
    // ...    
}
```

By designating the method as [`sychronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6), the JVM will allow no more than one thread at a time to execute that method.

There are other ways of writing thread safe code, but unless and until you have a specific reason to use them, using synchronized it great – it's simple, correct, and easy to understand / reason about.